# How to remove everything before the first specific character in a string?

Tags: php, string, replace

My variables look like this:

**AAAAAAA, BB CCCCCCCC**

**AAAA,BBBBBB CCCCCC**

I would like to remove everything before the "`,`",

so the results should look like:

**BB CCCCCCCC**

**BBBBBB CCCCCC**

I have worked out this to remove everything AFTER the "`,`":

```
list($xxx) = explode(',', $yyyyy);
```

unfortunately I dont know how to get it to work to remove everything BEFORE the "`,`".

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->afterFirst(',')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L435) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: `$xxx = explode(',', $yyyyy, 2)[1];`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using explode, as it causes more issues if there is more than one comma.

```
// removes everything before the first ,
$new_str = substr($str, ($pos = strpos($str, ',')) !== false ? $pos + 1 : 0);
```

Edit:

```
if(($pos = strpos($str, ',')) !== false)
{
   $new_str = substr($str, $pos + 1);
}
else
{
   $new_str = get_last_word($str);
}
```

Comment: this is the one you should use, IMHO

Comment: +1 -- It's faster and more readable (IMHO) than the regexp. Go with this.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: This fails however when there isn't any comma. `strpos()` returns false when there isn't a comma, `false + 1` = 1 which means you'll end up stripping your first character.

Comment: @Andrew: Fixed so it doesn't fail if there is no comma present. I do prefer your regex solution over this.

Comment: Yes, this worked great! One last thing: is it possible to include a "if" statement that, in case there is no ",", will use another function to use the last word of the string?

Comment: use trim() like my example below

Comment: @Andrej: Do you need assistance with getting the last word in the string?

Comment: @Tim: I have a function already that outputs the last word of a given string. I have problems to tell the script to use that function in case there is NO ",". If thats even possible.

Comment: p.s. i think you forgot a ")" after "if(($pos = strpos($str, ',')" it works great with "if(($pos = strpos($str, ','))"

Comment: check mine below for better-ness ;P what is "get_last_word"

Answer (score 27):

Since this is a simple string manipulation, you can use the following to remove all characters before the first comma:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^[^,]*,\s*/', '', $input);
```

[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) allows you to replace parts of a string based on a regular expression. Let's take a look at the regular expression.

> - `/    is the start delimiter`
>
>   - `^    is the "start of string" anchor`
>   - `[^,] every character that isn't a comma (^ negates the class here)`
>
>     - `*    repeated zero or more times`
>   - `,    regular comma`
>   - `\s   any whitespace character`
>
>     - `*    repeated zero or more times`
> - `/    end delimiter`

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend.

Comment: What if I want to remove every char before **and including** comma?

Comment: I've been looking for the same. End up by replacing the `''` with `','` so the complete code will become: `$string = preg_replace('/^[^,]*,\s*/', ',', $input);`

Answer (score 2):

```
list(,$xxx) = explode(',', $yyyyy, 2);
```

Comment: Also: `$xxx = explode(',', $yyyyy, 2)[1];`.

Answer (score 2):

try this it gets the last stuff after the , if no , is present it will check from the last space, i wrapped it in a function to make it easy:

```
<?php 
$value='AAAA BBBBBB CCCCCC';
function checkstr($value){
    if(strpos($value,',')==FALSE){
        return trim(substr(strrchr($value, ' '), 1 ));  
    }else{
        return trim(substr($value, strpos($value,',')),',');
    }
}

echo checkstr($value);
?>
```

Comment: this works good too! but how can i tell the script to use the last word of the string in case there is no "," ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
$arr = explode(',', $yyyyy);
unset($arr[0]);
echo implode($arr);
```

Comment: I think this is nice. Though you need to echo implode(',',$arr); to not lose the other commas.

Comment: @embe there are no other commas in the question's example

Comment: True. It was in my case, and to answer "Remove Everything Before the first “,” in a string" I think it's good to add. Thank you for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is generally expensive and i wouldn't recommend it for something as simple as this. 
Using explode and limiting it to 2 will probably result in the same execution time as using str_pos but you wouldn't have to do anything else to generate the required string as its stored in the second index.

```
 //simple answer 
 $str = explode(',', $yyyyy,2)[1];
```

OR

```
//better 

$arr = explode(',', $yyyyy,2);
$str = isset($arr[1]) ? $arr[1] : '';
```