# PHP - Return everything after delimiter

Tags: php, string

There are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329866/remove-everything-before-the-first-in-a-string) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588666/remove-all-after-delimiter-php) in SO, but I couldn't find any exactly like this. I need to remove everything up to (and including) a particular delimiter. For example, given the string `File:MyFile.jpg`, I need to remove everything up to the `:`, so that I'm left with only `MyFile.jpg`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SubirKumarSao he's talking about PHP

Comment: I thought of `substr`, but the length of the substring before the delimiter may vary. I guess I need to combine it with `strpos`, but haven't figured the best way yet.

Comment: Corrected. When I noticed the php tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: this one works fine.

```
$str = "File:MyFile.jpg";
$str = substr( $str, ( $pos = strpos( $str, ':' ) ) === false ? 0 : $pos + 1 );
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't really helpful. Please add some explanation.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks. Could be simplified to `substr( $str, strpos( $str, ':' ) )` if one knew that the `:` _does_ appear in the string.

Comment: thats why used another substr :-)

Answer (score 9):

Use this preg_replace call:

```
$str = 'File:MyFile.jpg';
$repl = preg_replace('/^[^:]*:/', '', $str); // MyFile.jpg
```

OR else avoid regex and use explode like this:

```
$repl = explode(':', $str)[1]; // MyFile.jpg
```

**EDIT:** Use this way to avoid regex (if there can be more than one : in string):

```
$arr = explode(':', 'File:MyFile.jpg:foo:bar');
unset($arr[0]);
$repl = implode(':', $arr); // MyFile.jpg:foo:bar
```

Comment: Note: `explode(':', $str)[1]` doesn't work in PHP (upto 5.3.8 at least)

Comment: Absolutely right @Ejay, `explode(':', $str)[1]` works since PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: Regular expressions for such a simple task?

Comment: As to the `explode`, if there is more than one `:` it won't work, right?

Comment: @FelipeSchenone: If there can be more than one `:` in the string then you can either use preg_replace or use my edited answer on explode.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using explode, as it causes more issues if there is more than one delimiter .

Answer (score 3):

Shorter codes:

To return everything **BEFORE** the ***FIRST*** occurence of a character, use `strtok`. Example:

- `strtok(16#/en/go, '#')` will return `16`

To return everything **AFTER** the ***FIRST*** occurence of a character, use `strstr`. Example:

- `strstr(16#/en/go, '#')` will return `#/en/go` (Includes search character
  '#')
- `substr(strstr(16#/en/go, '#'), 1)` will return `/en/go`

To return everything **AFTER** the ***LAST*** occurrence of a character, use `strrchr`. Example:

- `strrchr(16#/en/go, '/')` will return `/go` (Includes search character
  '/')
- `substr(strrchr(16#/en/go/, '/'), 1)` will return `go`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `explode` to do this: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Something like:

```
$string = "File:MyFile.jpg";
list($protocol,$content) = explode(":", $string);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $str = "File:MyFile.jpg";

    $position = strpos($str, ':');//get position of ':'

    $filename= substr($str, $position+1);//get substring after this position
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer ... most sensible, brief and efficient.  Can be shortened as: `substr($str, strrpos($str, ":")+1);`

Comment: ...but this fails if the delimiter is not found ...which is why is should NOT be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways:

```
$filename = str_replace('File:', '', 'File:MyFile.jpg');
```

or

```
$filename = explode(':', 'File:MyFile.jpg');
$filename = $filename[1];
```

Comment: The first one will work for the example, but not in the general case. The second one seems like an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sample String:

```
$string = 'value:90|custom:hey I am custom message|subtitute:array';
```

convert string to array

```
$var = explode('|', $string);
```

Check Results:

```
Array(
[0] => value:90
[1] => custom:hey I am custom message
[2] => subtitute:array)
```

Declare an array variable

```
$pipe = array();
```

Loop through string array $var

```
foreach( $var as $key => $value ) {
  // get position of colon
  $position = strrpos( $value, ':' );
  // get the key
  $key = substr( $value, 0, $position );
  //get the value
  $value = substr( $value, $position + 1 );
  $pipe[$key] = $value; }
```

Final Result:

```
Array(
[value] => 90
[custom] => hey I am custom message
[subtitute] => array)
```