# Remove everything up to and including character in PHP string

Tags: php, string

I'm looking for a non-regex solution (if possible) to the following problem:

I'd like to remove everything *up to and including* a particular string within a string.

So, for example, `£10.00 - £20.00` becomes just `£20.00`, maybe by providing the function with `-` as a parameter.

I've tried `strstr` and `ltrim`, but neither were quite what I was after.

Comment: Why non-regex ? its one of the most wonderful things in programming. You can use it for so much?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove everything before the first specific character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329866/how-to-remove-everything-before-the-first-specific-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved using string manipulation functions in PHP. First we find the position of the `-` character in the string using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos). Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) to get everything until that character (including that one). Then use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) to remove whitespace from the beginning and/or end of the string:

```
echo trim(substr($str, strpos($str, '-') + 1)); // => £20.00
```

Alternatively, you could split the string into two pieces, with `-` as the delimiter, and take the second part:

```
echo trim(explode('-', $str)[1]);
```

This could be done in many different ways. In the end, it all boils down to your preferences and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this would work:

```
$str="£10.00 - £20.00";
$arr=explode(" - ",$str);
echo $arr[1];
```

Answer (score -3):

Use substr().

```
$string = "£10.00 - £20.00";
$result = substr($string, -6);
echo $result;
```

Comment: this is a bad answer
it solve this case only - what will happen if its : $string = "£9.00 - £20.00";